# Writing to file with concise syntax

Tags: python-3.x

Is there way I can make code below more compact?

`header*` are string variables.

```
output_file.write(header1)
output_file.write("\n")
output_file.write(header2)
output_file.write("\n")
output_file.write(header3)
output_file.write("\n")
output_file.write(header4)
output_file.write("\n")
output_file.write(header5)
output_file.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `str.format`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

In your case:

```
"{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n".format(
  header1, header2, header3, header4, header5
)
```

If you had them in a list like `headers = [header1, header2, header3, header4, header5]`, it would be even easier:

```
"{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n".format(*headers)
```

Then again, you could also use `str.join`:

```
"\n".join(headers)
```